# Can't display data to my textarea in PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am not able to display data to my text area. I'm testing out to display question on textarea and my database structure only have id and question that include one question.

I will appreciate those who will try to give me guidance.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Question</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <!--<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>-->
            <li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Question App</h3>
      </div>
      <form action="question.php" method="post">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Question</b></td>
          <br />
          <td><textarea name="question" disabled cols="80%" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2016 Login App, Inc.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';

$records = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE id = 1");
$records->execute();
$results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code doesn't try to print the question to the textarea, try

```
<textarea name="question" disabled cols="80%" rows="10">
     <?echo $results['question']?>
</textarea>
```

assuming `question` is the name of your database column

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display data from your questions. The simplest way will be

Change your HTML file's extension to .php

and

```
<tr>
   <td><b>Question</b></td><br />
   <td>
      <textarea name="question" disabled cols="80%" rows="10">
         <?php include('question.php'); ?>
      </textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and make sure your print data in your question.php